# $F = \langle yz-2xy^2, axz-2x^2y+z, xy+y \rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given that:
$$F = \langle yz-2xy^2, axz-2x^2y+z, xy+y \rangle$$
in which $a$ is some constant.

Now, for what $a$ would make the vector field of $F$ conservative? How can we find an $f$ with $\nabla f=F$? Also for what $a$ would $F$ be the curl of another vector field?

Comment: For the first question I got $a=1$. For the second question I got $f(x,y,z)=xyz-x^2y^2+C$. And for the third question I got, any $a$ is suitable.

Comment: @coldnumber Yes, but I am asking for verification of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\vec F=\hat x(yz-2xy^2)+\hat y(axz-2x^2y+z)+\hat z(xy+y)$ and seek a scalar field $f$ such that $\nabla f=\vec F$.

Start with the $z$-component of $\vec F$.  This component must be equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.  Thus, we can write

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=xy+y\implies f=(xy+y)z+g(x,y)$$

---

Now, let's move to the $x$-component of $\vec F$.  This component must be equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.  Thus, we can write

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=yz+\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}=yz-2xy^2\implies g(x,y)=-x^2y^2-xy+h(y)$$

---

And finally, we move to the $y$-component of $\vec F$. This component must be equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.  Thus, we can write

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=xz+z-2x^2y+h'(y)=axz-2x^2y+z\implies a=1,\,\,\text{and}\,\,h(y)=C$$

---

Putting it all together, if

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{a=1}$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(x,y,z)=xyz+yz-x^2y^2+C}$$

then $\vec F$ is conservative with

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\vec F(x,y,z)=\nabla f(x,y,z)}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.